# Print each array items from arraylist in single line

Tags: java, arraylist

I am getting output from my java program in below format.

> [race, care, acre][act, cat]

Expected: Each array elements in different line.

> race care acre
>     act cat

I already tried to print but getting.

> race care acre act cat

Is there any way around so i can get expected results. Below is the gist of my code. Thanks

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            Scanner sc = readWords();
            Map<String, List<String>> wordAnagramPairs = new HashMap<>();
            wordAnagramPairs = mapAnagrams(sc);
            for (String anagram : wordAnagramPairs.keySet()) {
                if (wordAnagramPairs.get(anagram).size() > 1) {
                    System.out.print(wordAnagramPairs.get(anagram));
//                    for(String anagrams : wordAnagramPairs.get(anagram)){
//                        System.out.print(anagrams + " ");
//                    }
                }
            }



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use print with \n new line

```
for (String anagram : wordAnagramPairs.keySet()) {
    if (!wordAnagramPairs.get(anagram).isEmpty()) {
        for (String word : wordAnagramPairs.get(anagram)) {
         System.out.print(word+" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make you for statement use `println` if you want to print each element on a new line:

```
for(String anagrams : wordAnagramPairs.get(anagram)){
                        System.out.println(anagrams + " ");
                   }
```

If you want to print out each array element on a single line, but have each array on a separate line, you would do something like this:

```
for (String anagram : wordAnagramPairs.keySet()) { 
                //You need to make this 0 rather than 1 if you want to print 
                //out an array with one element
                if (wordAnagramPairs.get(anagram).size() > 0) {
                    for(String anagrams : wordAnagramPairs.get(anagram)){
                        System.out.print(anagrams + " ");
                    }

                }
            //you need to put a print statement outside the second for loop
            System.out.println("");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

"\n" is a sign of a newline. Is that what you are looking for?
or use println instead of print

Take a look here (escape characters sub-topic) if you need an explaination https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html